# How many disk space oracle synonym takes?

Tags: oracle, storage, space, disk, synonym

We've a problem at my company because everyone shares the development oracle database. Thus, if a developer wants to modify a procedure or package, for example, other's application will fail, until this first developer ends his work.

So I thought it will be great if I could create a User in my database **for each demand of work** within a synonym (or many) for datase objects.

Here comes the example:

I have a demand called *D9877*, for instance. My work on this demand is to alter a package named *MYPCKG*. So to start assignment, I first create a Oracle user as *D9877* within a synonym for my *MYPCKG*. This way, any modification will be applied on synonym, without affecting any other developers.

And here are my questions:

- Could I do that without my server storage explodes?
- How many disk space a oracle synonym takes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your understanding of synonyms is not quite correct.

Synonym is a link on another object. As a shortcut on file on Windows or link on Linux.

To be able to parallel change of some packages you need to make sure that your application could be installed on dedicated schema. You can create local synonyms on you tables (because tables do take space!) from main application schema and compile packages in your schema. Another developers can have their own version of application (i.e. packages, views).

However you need to consider some cases like triggers (it could be tricky to have 2 versions of the trigger on the same table), some dynamic DDL to tables executed by your application, like truncate table and etc.

Comment: So I think dedicated schemas would help me. Although it would still take much disk space, wouldn't it?

Comment: As I mentioned, disk space in database is taken by tables (tablespaces) but not by other objects. Other objects are registered in system dictionary. It will probably take couple more megs - you should not worry about it. My point is that in you private schema you keep only compilable objects - packages - but all tables with data you keep in main schema. So you won't duplicate data

Answer (score 1):

Synonym takes several bytes of disk space, but it isn't important at all. This approach will not solve this problem.

First of all it seems like you misunderstand what synonym means. It's an other name for the same object. You cannot 'apply modifications to the synonym', but even if you can, you'll modify the object itself.

Sometimes synonyms can be used to distinguish package versions. Say, you have package A; all uses it. You can make packages A_VERSION_1 and A_VERSION_2, public synonym A for A_VERSION_2 and private synonym A for A_VERSION_2. If you do so, you'll can to debug your application with A_VERSION_2 while all others works with A_VERSION_1.

Bad news is this approach does not work too. It works only when you directly call A from your application. But let's imagine we have two packages, A and B (authid definer). B uses A. You call B from your application and you should to modify A. In this case B will never look to your private synonym. You'll be in need to make B_VERSION_2 with it's private synonym too etc. In view of number of intercalls between database objects it's impossible way to use.

Comment: If you have the correct permissions on the object then you can certainly "apply modifications to the synonym"; it will modify the object as you say.

Comment: How? I don't know such ability. If using CREATE OR REPLACE it will not de-reference synonym. If using ALTER PACKAGE it cannot change body (and it will not de-reference synonym too).

Comment: If you `alter package <synonym name> compile`  (for example) and the user has the correct permissions on the actual package you will be allowed to compile the package. I didn't say that a synonym is anything other than a pointer as you describe.